# Gitlab CI for multiple app folder in 1 Project Repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have following setup
1 Project repo with
–> App1 (source code)
–> App2 (source code)

Now we have single(1) .gitlab-ci.yml at repo level.

What we want to achieve is:

With each checkin/commit to Apps (App1 or App2) should trigger CI build and push its own artifacts to registry.

Can we execute Gitlab-CI[with the same .gitlab-ci.yml from root level] based upon commit/checkin specific Folder Name Apps (App1 or App2)(which has the commit changes ,to be build) ?

Is it possible?

Please guide.

Comment: what do you mean 'can we do parameterze'? do you want to trigger a different build step by the committed code?

Comment: Thanks Amityo , what I mean to say is that by parameterise is that same CI file getting fired upon commit into any of Apps (App1 or App2) in the single Repo Project

Answer (score 0):

If you run a specific stage based on the changes in App1 or App2 you can use the only+ changes keywords:

> Using the changes keyword with only or except, makes it possible to define if a job should be created based on files modified by a git push event.

Define two stages - one for App1, one for App2 and add the only + changes keyword:

```
build_App1:
  script: ...
  only:
    changes:
      - path/to/App1/**/*
```

see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges) for more details. And make sure to read the caveats [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#using-changes-with-new-branches-and-tags)